# Making Batch for /f code work propely

Tags: batch-file

Here is my file that is trying to read hosts file. For some reason, it's not workin properly. Try the code yourself to see the error messages.

```
@echo off
cd %windir%/System32/drivers/etc
for /f  "eol=# tokens=* delims=," %%a in (%windir%/System32/drivers/etc/hosts) do type %%a
pause>nul
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type` expects a file name. you probably meant `echo`. 
as another issue, the hosts file is not comma, but whitespace separated. so you'll need to change your delims to include space and tab, assuming you want to have only the hostname.